# What is an avif file signature?

Tags: avif

I have searched it from [here](https://www.filesignatures.net/), [here](https://handwiki.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures), [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) but none of them included the avif signature.

I want to determine whether a file is avif or not from bitstream. But document is too complex or cannot be accessed freely. How can I achieve this?

It will be better if answer includes the reason why it can be applied without false positive or false negative.

Answer (score 2):

The file signature for avif file is `ftypavif`.

You can see a list of sample avif files here:
https://github.com/link-u/avif-sample-images

To check file signatures yourself, download/find a file you want to check, then you can check via any hex viewer.

In Powershell on Windows, you can run this:

```
format-hex c:\yourfile.someextension
```

[image: format-hex in Powershell]

Comment: I want a method to determine whether a file is an avif or not in the end. I have an avif not having `ftypavif`. I need more solid way and a ground for that.

Comment: What signature does your file have when you run it through a hex viewer?

Comment: If I provide it, can you suggest a solution not having false negative? I can find no meaning to this.

Comment: Feel free to share the file